# How does Glass and myGlass app sync the views e.g. Joining wifi

Tags: google-glass

I recently downloaded the latest myGlass app and also updated the glass to XE19.1. Noticed that now the events can be fired from the device and they get executed on the glass. 
For example, if you are screen casting the glass onto the device, and are on the live card scroll view (timeline), you can scroll on the device screen and it will scroll on the glass as well.
Similarly, if you want to join a wifi network, the moment you select 'Join network' on glass, a dialog box appears on the connected device. I want to know and understand the mechanism of commands being triggered from both sides and being read and executed on the other. Can anyone please guide me as to how this is happening !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The MyGlass app uses a bluetooth channel to the Glass device for several operations, including the screencast and configuration from the smartphone/tablet. This channel isn't available to other developers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply 'Prisoner'. I have created a BT channel to pass on messages from glass to device and vice versa but thought I would pick up on someone's brain, if they know how google is using it, which is obviously better because they seem to be listening to and responding to events. I am still not able to find a way to trigger an event on either glass or device and execute it on the other. Will wait to see  if someone knows the mechanism.